# Reduced density matrix of two spins

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, many-body

I am reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.0062.pdf) (https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0062) article about constructing order parameters from reduced density matrix. The author is discussing long-range order by taking antiferromagnetic spin chain as an example. By considering state
$$|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow\downarrow\cdots\uparrow\downarrow\rangle +|\downarrow\uparrow\cdots\downarrow\uparrow\rangle )$$
reduced density matrix of a single spin is written as
$$\rho_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2&0\\0&1/2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and reduced density matrix for two spins at sites $i$ and $j$ is written as
$$\rho_{2e}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1/2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for even $|i-j|$ and for odd $|i-j|$
$$\rho_{2o}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&1/2&0&0\\
0&0&1/2&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
**I want to rederive above three matrices.**

---

**My attempt:**

Density matrix for a single site $i$ is defined as
$$\rho_i=\sum_\mu p_\mu|\phi_{i\mu}\rangle \langle \phi_{i\mu} |$$
where $p_\mu$ is probability of pure state $|\phi_{i\mu}\rangle$. And for two sites $i, j$
$$\rho_{i\bigcup j}=\sum_{\mu,\nu} p_{\mu,\nu}|\phi_{i\mu,j\nu}\rangle\langle\phi_{i\mu,j\nu}|$$

**For single spin,** I was able to understand that the basis set can be {$|\uparrow\rangle,|\downarrow\rangle$}. And probability for each state is $1/2$. So, the reduced density matrix become
$$\rho_1\equiv\rho_i=1/2(|\uparrow\rangle \langle \uparrow|+|\downarrow\rangle \langle \downarrow|)$$
and writing this in matrix form gives the required form i.e. $diag(1/2,1/2)$.

**For two spins**, well, I am unable to rederive it. I thought that the basis {$|\uparrow\uparrow\rangle,|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle,|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle,|\downarrow\downarrow\rangle$} can reproduce above matrices *but* I get a matrix $diag(1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4)$. Also, I can not understand how even and odd values of $|i-j|$ can have any impact on the matrices?

Comment: Do you know about the partial trace and how it relates to reduced density matrices?

Comment: @DanielSank I think I know but I do not understand how is it going to help here. Partial trace is basically tracing out the specific degree of freedom. For example, for two density matrices $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ the composite density matrix is $\rho_{AB}=\sum_{ijkl} p_{ijkl}|a_i\rangle\langle a_j| \otimes |b_k\rangle \langle b_l|$, then the trace over B will be $\sum_{ijkl} p_{ijkl} |a_i\rangle\langle a_j|\langle b_k | b_l \rangle$. Correct me if I am wrong. I am new to information theory. I would appreciate if you recommend me some books to understand this kind of mathematics.